# get the core file in perl script with backtick

Tags: linux, perl, unix

On my ubuntu 14.04 (Linux 3.19.0 64bit) PC, I ran a perl program that has the following in a loop

```
$params = setupParams();
$ret = `SOME_CMD $params`;
...
```

But for some reason, SOME_CMD sometimes gaves `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` occasionally. In order to figure out the cause of the core dump, I need to get the core file. 
Unfortunately I tried `ulimit -S -c 0` on the terminal where I ran the perl script, but it didn't produce a core file.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: isn't the `core` file dumped in the "current working directory" of `SOME_CMD`?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com is probably a better place for this question, but figuring out how to get a core file in order to debug a program is also programming-related, and thus allowed on this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ulimit -c 0` prevents core files to be written. You need to use
`ulimit -c unlimited`

Btw: you should upgrade to a maintained OS.